# Graph theory - the count of edges

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G^n_k=(V,E)$ be graph with $|V|=n$ vertices and exactly $k$ connected components. 
Find

$$\max_{G_{n,k}}|E|,$$
i.e. what is the maximum number of edges possible in such a graph?

Thank you for any hints.

Comment: If you have two components of size $a$ and $b$, then $a+b=n$. You don't have edges between the two components, so the number of edges in total will be the sum of the edges in each of the two components; now, how many edges (at most) can a graph with $a$ nodes have?

Comment: I think the graph with $a$ nodes can have $(a-1)$ edges ?

Comment: No -- think of a fully connected graph on $a$ nodes.

Comment: Fully connected its $a \choose 2$ ? So will can be total sum of the edges of two components $a \choose 2$ + $b \choose 2$ - 1 ?

Comment: Why $-1$? But then, you need to maximize it by choosing the "best" $a,b$.

Comment: I mean ${a \choose 2}$ is total count edges od component 1 and ${b \choose 2}$ component 2 and $-1$ like without edges between the two components. So total sum of the edges of two components are ${a \choose 2}$ + ${b \choose 2}$. But I dont know what you mean "best" now? Can you describe it more please?

Comment: You need to figure out what setting of $a,b$ maximizes the number of edges, now. The only constraint is $a+b=n$, and $a,b \geq 1$.

Comment: @user288083 please verify the question is still what you wanted to ask after my edit. Also if you satisfied with the answer it would be nice if you accept it by clicking on the v under the arrows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a graph $G$ has $n$ vertices and $\ell \in \mathbb N_+$ components, 
then it has at most $\frac{1}{2} \cdot (n-\ell) \cdot (n-\ell+1)$ edges.
You choose $\ell \in \{2,3\}$ to get your answer.

In detail:

Let $m$ be the number of edges of $G$.
Consider that any upper bound for $m$ must remain valid if all components of $G$ are complete graphs. 
Assume that $H_1, H_2 \subseteqq G$ are such complete components with $|H_1| = n_{H_1} \geq n_{H_2} = |H_2|$.
If we replace these subgraphs by two complete graphs of order $n_{H_1}+1$ and $n_{H_2}-1$, respectively, 
then the total number of vertices of $G$ remains unchanged but the number of edges increases by $\left(\frac{(n_{H_1}+1)\cdot (n_{H_1}+1-1)}{2} + \frac{(n_{H_2}-1)\cdot(n_{H_2}-1-1)}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{n_{H_1}\cdot (n_{H_1}-1)}{2} + \frac{n_{H_2}\cdot(n_{H_2}-1)}{2}\right) = n_{H_1} - n_{H_2} + 1 > 0$.

So, the number of edges of $G$ will be at a maximum if there are $(\ell-1)$ isolated vertices and one component that is a complete graph with $(n-(\ell-1))$ vertices 
and $\frac{1}{2} \cdot (n-\ell) \cdot (n-\ell+1)$ edges.

Comment: Thank you, I trying it and it works good. Can I ask you how do you get this $\frac{1}{2} \cdot (n-\ell) \cdot (n-\ell+1)$ ? I am try to deduction but I can not discover it..

Comment: @☺user288083: I have added an explanation for the proposed result. Does it help you?

Comment: Yes, it does.I have once last question. Why we multiply all result expression by $\frac{1}{2}$ please?

Comment: @user288083: The factor $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from the consideration that a complete graph on $k$ vertices has $\frac{1}{2} k (k-1)$ edges. In your case $k = n - (\ell-1)$. OK?

Comment: Yes, I got it, thank you veru much