# A simple graph G of order n and has k components.

Tags: graph-theory

A simple graph **G** of order **n** and has **k** components then
\begin{align} 
      \ e(G)\leq \frac{\ (n-k)(n-k+1)}{2} \\
    \end{align}
For example, in the image below, there are total 4 vertices but max 2 edges are possible for each sub-graph component-1 and component-2

[image: problem]

Comment: what is your point? that the inequality is false? or that it is not strict?

Comment: btw the inequality is strict; you can get equality by having $k-1$ isolated vertices and a complete graph on $n-k+1$ vertices. In this case that would be a triangle and a lone point.

Comment: yeah, I just don't know what is confusing OP

Comment: For the case of one graph, (n)(n-1)/2 is always valid when it`s a complete graph, but not in the case of multiple components? For example, a single connected component with 4 vertices have 6 edges at max which is valid.

Comment: @Heyo: Check out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558710/graph-theory-the-count-of-edges/1558789#1558789

Answer (score 4):

The claim is that the number of edges in any graph with $k$ components and $n$ vertices is at most $\binom{n-k+1}{2}=\frac{(n-k)(n-k+
)1}{2}$.
And the inequality is strict consider the example for $n=4,k=2$:

[image]

For general $n$ and $k$ you can pick the graph with $k-1$ isolated points and a clique with $n-k+1$ points.

Comment: Now it makes sense, thanks a lot :)