# Maximum possible of edges

Tags: graph-theory

Show that if G is a simple graph with n vertices and p connected components, the maximum possible number of edges in G is $\frac{1}{2}(n-p)(n-p+1)$

I know when G is simple, the max number of edges is $\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$, but with the condition p connected components imposed, I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Check out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558710/graph-theory-the-count-of-edges/1558789#1558789

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The maximum number of edges arises when the graph consists of $p-1$ isolated vertices and a component with $n-p+1$ vertices all connected to each other.

Prove this by showing that any graph *not* of this form can be modified to have more edges in total without changing the number of vertices and connected components.

Comment: Do you mean that if I have $p-2$ isolated vertices and 2 components, one with $x$ vertices and  one with $n-p+2-x$ vertices, having more edges?

Comment: @mathshungry: In that case you can increase the number of edges by moving a vertex from the smaller of the components to the larger.